# Heating diamonds

Tags: energy

This is research for a Victorian-era detective story. If a diamond the size of the Koh-i-Noor sat at the bottom of a gaslamp globe for less than an hour, what effect would the flame have? Would the diamond even get hot?

Comment: What is the size of the Koh-i-Noor? ;) You might narrow your question down to something specific to chemistry here. For thermal conductivity you might ask in Physics SE. You might also add a diagram or image of a gaslamp globe with the location of the diamond so one could estimate how close to the flame it is sitting, and what it is touching, and of course indicate how big it is.

Comment: However it looks like you've already received a [great answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/76272/16035) so much for my suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

It might get hot (diamond is a very good thermal conductor) and depending on where it's sitting in relation to the flame, it might get some soot deposited on it, but it likely wouldn't burn.
While it is possible to burn diamonds, it takes fairly high temperatures and a ready supply of oxygen to do it, [[1]](https://www.gemsociety.org/article/can-diamonds-burn/) so it generally doesn't happen without an external source of oxygen (or being [outright dropped into liquid oxygen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tcP9SLKEG4)).

Comment: Great links on burning diamonds - much to be learned there! Actually, being a good thermal conductor is a reason for it not to get as hot as something that is a poor conductor, which could get much hotter on the side exposed to the flame. The conductivity would spread the heat instantly across the whole object, offering more cooling area. That's why some people look into [diamond-like carbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-like_carbon#Electrical) films for removal of heat in electronics.